# Redirect everything but few pages in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a subdomain leading to website hosted in subfolder containing :

- a subfolder named `r`, inside of which I have my CSS and other resources files (you'll understand why I have this folder later)
- few files such as `privacy-policy.php`, `imprint.php`,...
- a script `index.php`

I want that the user type `http://www.example.com/STRING`, he got served `http://www.example.com/index.php?code=STRING` except when this would lead to an existing page when adding back the `.php`(i.e.  `http://www.example.com/privacy-policy`, `http://www.example.com/imprint`)

Right now, my nginx conf file gives this

```
    location /subfolder/ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php index.php?code=$uri;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            location /subfolder/r/ {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            }
    }
```

The subfolder `r` has been created so that the static files are not processed by PHP.

This works well for the static files inside the `r` subfolder, also works well for the `imprint.php` type, but it does not work for the redirect to `index.php?code=$uri`.

Why is that?

Comment: All Nginx URIs begin with a `/`. Also, is `index.php` inside the subfolder? You could try: `/subfolder/index.php?code=$uri`

Comment: The problem has been solved but the code is the same... I have no idea what was wrong...